# Serilog configuration for microsoft still overrides logging information level logs

Tags: serilog

I have the following settings defined, but I am still getting all put/get requests logged to my api, even though these are supposed to be "Microsoft".

Can anyone share advice?

```json
      "Serilog": {
        "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
        "MinimumLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Override": {
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "System": "Warning"
          }
        },
        "WriteTo": [
          { "Name": "Console" },
          {
            "Name": "Seq",
            "Args": { "serverUrl": "http://logserver:5341" }
          },
          {
            "Name": "File",
            "Args": {
              "path": "c:\\temp\\events.api.txt",
              "rollingInterval": "Day"
            }
          }
        ],
        "Properties": {
          "Application": "Events API"
        }
      },
```

Example of a log:

> [13:55:10 INF] Source:[::1] Request: PUT https localhost:44320/api
> {json request object} Responded with [200] in 2ms

```cs
return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext());
            });
```

Comment: You should be using `Host.UseSerilog()`, not the old web host thing; not sure if this will be the cause, though (possible that you're overriding levels in an _appsettings.Development.json_?)

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt i double checked, there is nothing in my .Development.json, but that was a good thought, also switched to .Host.UseSerilog, it didnt make a difference